# listings numbers are wrong (i need sequence)

Tags: listings, counters

I'm having a problem letting the numbering of listings in sequence. In the images the tex usually counts: 1,2,3,4 ...
However, in the listings, he takes the format "chapter . number."

I almost got the result with the command:

```
\ AtBeginDocument {\ renewcommand * {\ thelstlisting} {\ arabic {lstlisting}}}
```

However, when i start a new chapter, the count is reset. How do I leave sequence for all chapters?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.se  Your question doesn't give enough information to give you a complete answer. Can you post a minimal compilable document that shows what you're doing. It needs to have only the following content other than the minimal preamble needed to compile: two chapters, with one empty figure+caption and one empty listing+caption in each chapter, your `\listoffigures` and `lstlistoflistings`. NOTHING ELSE.  Edit your question with that and then we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{lstlisting}{chapter}`. Untested.

Comment: @cfr If you'd tested, you'd have seen you need to wrap it in `\AtBeginDocument{}`. :)  But yes, that will probably do the trick.

Comment: @AlanMunn If I'd had code to test, I'd have tested.

Comment: @AlanMunn I've never used `lstlistlistings` or whatever it is. I'm not going to learn it just to make an MWE!

Comment: @cfr: The `lstlisting` counter is (strangely) defined after `\begin{document}` (or `\AtBeginDocument`), that's why you need the `\AtBeginDocument` as suggested by Alan Munn.